# entity model relationship pizzeria

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to make an entity model relationship of a delivery of a pizzeria but I can't elaborate a model that meets my need.

I made my diagram using `brmodelo`, basically it has 10 entities:

- `client`
- `order`
- `orderItem`
- `wine`
- `beer`
- `otherDrinks`
- `pizza`
- `pizzaPrice` (because of there are five different sizes of pizzas and I think its better if I make one table for it)
- `ingredient`
- `pasta`

The problem is between the relationship of wine, beer, otherDrink, pizza and pasta with orderItem.

- How can I do these relationships correctly?
- If I do it the way it is on the image, I won't be able to distinguish
  the product id in the table orderItem.

I tried to simplify creating a table Product for all (`wine`, `beer`, `pizza`, `otherDrinks`) but I could't bcs each one of this option has a different information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your design as below. It should help you.

```
Product(ProdId, ProdType, UnitPrice, OtherCoomonColumns, ...) --Primary Key ProdId
Wine(ProdId, ProdDetails, SpecificColumns, ...)   --Uses foreign key ProdId
Pizza(ProdId, ProdDetails, SpecificColumns, ...)  --Uses foreign key ProdId
.......   Similar Table for Other Products......
```

In this way, you can provide unique ProdId in OrderItem table irrespective of product type.

Comment: Thanks! With some adjustments it worked very well! ;)